# know if user changed content in TWTweetComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

is there a way to know if the user changed the initial text of the tweet?
i'm trying to prevent the user from changing the predefined tweet, is that possible using the TWTweetComposeViewController in the iOS 5?

Comment: This is probably against the usage guidelines as you'd effectively be boosting hashtagging etc to get exposure

Comment: great @MDT thanks, it works. post your comment so i can accept it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for this, in Apple's Twitter sample code they show how to simply send a tweet without the users confirmation... No TWTeetComposer, no opportunity to change your predefined text.

[Apple's Twitter sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Tweeting/Introduction/Intro.html)